# Co vs Rh atomic radius

Tags: atomic-radius

Why is the empirical atomic radius for both Co and Rh 135 pm, the same?

[Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_radii_of_the_elements_(data_page))

Comment: Why not? Why can't two elements have a similar radius, particularly considering how fuzzy a concept it is in the first place?